# Django can't migrate on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have problem with migrating my database on Heroku trying to run `heroku run python manage.py migrate`. I always get this error:

```
(venv) E:\Studia\advise\promotion>heroku run python manage.py migrate
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ pro-motion... up, run.6349 (Free)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 325, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/promotion/settings.py", line 27, in <module>
    DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decouple.py", line 197, in __call__
    return self.config(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decouple.py", line 85, in __call__
    return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decouple.py", line 79, in get
    return cast(value)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decouple.py", line 50, in _cast_boolean
    raise ValueError('Not a boolean: %s' % value)
ValueError: Not a boolean: True
```

[image: Heroku config]

Comment: What is the `DEBUG` setting set to?

Comment: In ".env" File DEBUG is False

Comment: @MarcinNieznalski, is your `.env` file checked in? (It probably shouldn't be; Heroku has its own config var system to set environment variables.)

Comment: I upload a image with heroku config vars

Comment: First of all, you should probably [rotate your PostgreSQL credentials](https://blog.heroku.com/rotate_database_credentials_on_heroku_postgres_). You've just published (most of) them online and they're forever compromised. Also, please change your secret key.

Comment: Now that that's out of the way, your `DEBUG` environment variable seems to contain extra whitespace. Depending on how (or if) you use this environment variable to set your Heroku `DEBUG` value this may be a problem. Try deleting that whitespace and see if that helps.

Comment: I got it, DEBUG contains extra whitespaces @Chris thanks !!! 
Migrations works perfectly :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot shows a `DEBUG` environment variable whose value contains extra whitespace.

Depending on how you use that variable, the whitespace could easily caus problems. Delete that extra whitespace and see if that fixes things.

---

Also, you've partly revealed your `SECRET_KEY` and PostgreSQL credentials. Please change the `SECRET_KEY` and [rotate your database credentials](https://blog.heroku.com/rotate_database_credentials_on_heroku_postgres_). Your current values are no longer secure.